# Accounting for parameter change in LCIA

Tags: brightway

I have parametrized exchanges in a brightway process.
I want to see how changes in the parameters change the results of the LCA.
I can see that updating the parameters worked as the `amount` entry in my exchanges are modified.
However, `redo_lci(a)` do not seem to notice the change in the exchanges' amounts.

Is there an efficient way to redo the LCIA while recomputing the minimal amount of elements?
Namely:

- if I only modify exchanges with the biosphere, I think I don't need to recompute the demand and inventory
- if I only modify technosphere exchanges, I  think I don't need to recalculate the biosphere matrix
- if I modify both, then I guess I just have to recompute everything, anyway, so I should redo the LCA from scratch

Is this correct, and would there be a way avoiding unnecessary calculations in brightway?

Incidentally, shouldn't brightway detect that parameter changes make the LCA outdated and warn about it when calling `redo_lci(a)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an excellent question, and reflects the poor documentation currently available for parameterization. My fault, sorry!

There is a strong divide between the library that does the data management, including formulas and variables, and the LCA calculations. The LCA calculation library (`bw2calc`) has no idea that you have changed parameter values, and there is no easy way to change a parameter value and have that reflected in the LCA matrices other than creating a new `LCA` object each time.

However, there is an add-on library which was designed for exactly this use case: [presamples](https://presamples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It is well documented and should work.